# can blankly and merely be used interchangeably?

Tags: synonyms

I didn't see **merely** between synonyms of **blankly**, but base on definition I think they mean the same thing. Is it right?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please provide a context. No words are perfect synonyms but in certain contexts they can be interchangeable, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know can they be the same in some places or not.

Comment: you can edit your question by adding those "some places". "blankly" is more interchangeable with "barely" than with "merely", but this is only guessing without a real context.

Comment: "He looked at me blankly". Not a synonym at all.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing, not even close. I suppose that in certain contexts they might be interchangeable, but it is hard to imagine such a context. Either provide a context or the definitions you are relying on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There may be occasions when they overlap (though I can't think of any) but their meanings are quite different. *Blankly* refers to how a person is behaving or appearing; *merely* is a discourse comment (i.e. it has no objective meaning) about how significant or adequate something is.